# How do I query from two tables matching the foreign key from table with the primary key from another

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am currently creating a menu item and for the most part, it works but the information pulled is not correct for the 2nd level submenu(letters). I have tried so many different joins but either only pulls one of my submenu items or all of them. Not sure what I need to change at this point to make it work and not sure how to better explain the issue.

As for my **Tables**

```
menu :  columns id, name
people : id, people_name, href, menu_id
letters : id, letters_names, href, people_id
```

**My code is here:**

```
<?php
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=menu",'root','');
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessag();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="author" content="Kayla Lindstrom">
            <title>Lindstrom Letters</title>
           <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="page">
                <ul>
                    <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                        $sub_sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE menu_id=:id";
                        $sub_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub_sql);
                        $sub_stmt->bindParam(':id', $row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sub_stmt->execute(); 
                        ?>

                    <li><a href=""><?php echo $row->name; ?></a>
                        <?php if($sub_stmt->rowCount()){ ?>

                        <ul>
                        <?php while($sub_row = $sub_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
                            $sub2_sql = "SELECT * FROM letters WHERE people_id=:id"; /*Here is where I am stuck.*/
                            $sub2_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub2_sql);
                            $sub2_stmt->bindParam(':id', $row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);/*and here*/
                            $sub2_stmt->execute(); ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo $sub_row->href; ?>"> 
                            <?php echo $sub_row->people_name;?></a>
                            <?php if($sub2_stmt->rowCount()){ ?>

                                <ul>
                                <?php while($sub2_row = $sub2_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $sub2_row->href; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $sub2_row->letters_name;?></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </ul>

                            <?php } ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach your are doing one mistake, i guess,

Instead of this:

```
$sub2_stmt->bindParam(':id', $row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);/*and here*/
```

Try:

```
$sub2_stmt->bindParam(':id', $sub_row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);/*and here*/
```

And it should work. But you can achieve this by inner join, and with one query you can join all the tables.
Query should be like:

```
SELECT l.href, l.letters_name FROM menu m INNER JOIN people p ON m.id = p.menu_id INNER JOIN letters l ON l.people_id = p.id;
```

Comment: >_< Always once small thing I happened to overlook. Thank you! Sometimes I just need another pair of eyes to see what I am missing!